# How do I get the closest <li> to set .css height

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".mobile-handle").css({height: $("ul#active-tasks li").height()});
})
```

Here is my view code:

```
%li.task.clearfix[task]
  .mobile-handle
```

I am trying to set the height of the `.mobile-handle` to the height of the parent `li`. Still learning JS/Jquery so sorry I know this is elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets the height of each `.mobile-handle` to the height of its ancestor `li`

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".mobile-handle").each(function(){
        $(this).css({height: $(this).closest('li').height()});
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `closest`.
`"Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree."`
[reference](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".mobile-handle").css({
        'height': $("ul#active-tasks").closest('li').height()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the :parent selector will do.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".mobile-handle").css({height: $(".mobile-handle:parent").height()});
})
```

Comment: The [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) selector selects/filters all elements that have child element(s) (elements that ARE parents), so in your example you're selecting the `.mobile-handle` which has children, and not its parent. Try [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".mobile-handle").height( $("#active-tasks li").height() );
```

or

```
$(".mobile-handle").height( $(".mobile-handle").parent('li').height() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done bins for above query, you can find demo link too.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9d

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="active-tasks">
  <li>
    <div class="mobile-handle">
      Mobile-1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="mobile-handle">
      Mobile-2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="mobile-handle">
      Mobile-3
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="mobile-handle">
      Mobile-4
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#active-tasks{
  padding:4px;
  border:1px solid #445599;
  list-style:none;
  width:50%;
  background:#f9c8c5;
}
#active-tasks li{
  height:30px;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {

    $(".mobile-handle").height($(".mobile-handle").parent('li').height());
    /*
    //Another Alternate way is:
    $(".mobile-handle").height( $(".mobile-handle").closest('li').height() );*/

});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9d